# Artifact for making it possible to debug graaljs in Chrome

Tags: graalvm, graaljs

I'm trying to adopt debugging in graaljs:

```
Context.newBuilder("js")
                .option("inspect", port)
                .option("inspect.Path", path)
                .option("inspect.Remote", remoteConnect)
```

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find option with name inspect.`

My `build.gradle` dependencies look as follows:

```
def graalVersion = "1.0.0-rc15"

dependencies {
  compile "org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:${graalVersion}"
  compile "org.graalvm.js:js:${graalVersion}"
  compile "org.graalvm.js:js-scriptengine:${graalVersion}"
}
```

And I definitely remember that there used to be yet another dependency I should add to make it possible to debug in chrome - however I'm failing to remember - or find in any code source or documentation - what exactly I should add as a dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should also include the chromeinspector.
In maven that would be:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>chromeinspector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you've saved me from insanity - this is exactly the name of the dependency I've forgot about )